# R Studio 3.3.0 cannot load xlsx and rJava packages under Win 10

Tags: rstudio, xlsx, rjava

```
library(rJava)

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

I have reinstalled the latest Java and R Studio 3.3.0, but rJava and xlsx cannot be loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The packages likely aren't installed. When the minor version of R changes (3.2.5 > 3.3.0) the location of the library changes and you have to reinstall all packages : `install.packages(c('rJava','xlsx'))`

Alternatively you could navigate to your old library location and copy them to your new library but this will result in out of date packages.